# Unmarshalling with JAXBContext from another Module in WildFly

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb, classloader, wildfly

WildFly 8.2.1.

I have a "common" module in modules/system/layers/base.

Also I have a EAR with EJB-JAR inside
In this EAR I have jboss-deployment-structure.xml with dependence to the "common" module. It works ok, I can use Classes from that module.

But, when I try to construct `JAXBContext` on package inside that module, and try to unmarshal some xml to Object, I get

> unexpected element (uri:"{my namespace}", local:"{my local name}"). Expected elements are (none)

If I move that classes inside EJB-JAR(all in one module), unmarshalling works ok.

So it's something coming from modules separation.

I've tried to print `.toString()` from `JAXBContext` object.

With one module: All annotated classes are there.

With two modules: There is only `ObjectFactory` class from specified package there.

If I explicitly add the class to `JAXBContext`, I can see all need classes from `.toString()`, but unmarshalling is still not wirking. I get null object.

What it could be? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe have a look at alternate way of creating the JAXBContext and specify the TCCL instead of the default one:   https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)

Comment: @Franck, Yes, I have tried to use another `newInstance` method and specify `ClassLoader`. With both classloaders, from annotated class and through `org.jboss.modules.Module` API. Didn't worked. Result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried with Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()?

Comment: @Franck, Yes I have. Nothing changed...

Comment: I've just re-read your Question. The classes you're trying to unmarshall lives in the EJB module and the JAXBContext lives in the common one? Is it what you're doing?

Comment: @Franck, No, It's opposite.
Annotated classes lives in common module and JAXBContext is creating inside ejb-jar's deployment. And it's creating with the package(class) from common module. If these annotated classes were in ejb-jar, then it would work. But they are in another module. I can use them explicitly in ejb-jar, because i have dependency to common module in  jboss-deployment-structure.xml, but I cannot create JAXBContext with them.

Comment: @Franck, I have found the problem. Tomorrow will write an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.

But I don't completely understand what was the problem :) It's something with modules separation, class loading and class isolation in OSGi-like infrastructure thing.

To solve the problem, it must be added dependency in module.xml to "common" module for a "javax.xml.bind.api" like that:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="{module name}">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
        <resource-root path="common-types-1.0.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

It seems to be when this module is dependence to some deployment, it's not enough javax.xml.bind.api to present in that deployment for JAXBContext creation with those classes from common module. It needs to be added to common module as well.